# Can I change the filename of my ssh public/private key pair?

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh, xen, public-key-encryption

I created a public/private key pair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "me@example.com"
```

I gave a different key file name than id_rsa since I wanted to create a new separate key from my normal identity.

I gave this key to my hosting provider so that I can login to my server using public key authentication.

I was able to initially login using the key and everything worked.

```
ssh -i /path/to/key/file user@server.com
```

I realized I made a spelling error in the key file name and renamed both the public and private key files. Does this affect anything on the server side if the key file has a different name on my client machine?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The filename has no meaning at all, as long as `ssh` is told where to find it.

(However, if you have the public key extracted to a separate file, then it should have the same filename + `.pub` as the main file; e.g. `mykey` & `mykey.pub`.)

Comment: Any idea if it matters whether you change the comment within the .pub file?

Comment: @jjeaton: It doesn't.

Comment: "as long as ssh is told where to find it" - like entries in your .ssh/config file.
I'm here because I need two identities for the same git host, so two sets of keys and two hosts in my config pointing to the relevant user key.

Comment: SSH does look for some default filenames like `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, but other than that, the filenames of the keys don't matter.